# Require puppet to place a file before starting service

Tags: puppet

I am having trouble with our puppet config. When we go run puppet it is starting the php5-fpm service before it places the www.conf file. I have to then log in and restart the service for all to function as intended.

This is what I tried to do to the php/manifests/init.pp file:

```
    file { 'www.conf':
    path => '/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf',
    ensure => file,
    owner => root,
    group => root,
    source => 'puppet:///modules/php/www.conf',
    require => Package['php5-fpm'],
}

service { 'php5-fpm':
    ensure => running,
    enable => true,
    require => File['php.ini','www.conf'],
}
```

And here is the puppet output:

```
notice: /Stage[first]/Apt_get::Update/Exec[apt-get update]/returns: executed successfully
notice: /Stage[second]/Tools/Package[python-software-properties]/ensure: ensure changed 'purged' to 'present'
notice: /Stage[second]/Tools/Package[imagemagick]/ensure: ensure changed 'purged' to 'present'
notice: /Stage[second]/Tools/Package[curl]/ensure: ensure changed 'purged' to 'present'
notice: /Stage[third]/Php/Exec[add_repo]/returns: executed successfully
notice: /Stage[third]/Php/Exec[update_repo]/returns: executed successfully
notice: /Stage[third]/Php/Package[php5-mysql]/ensure: ensure changed 'purged' to 'latest'
notice: /Stage[third]/Php/Package[php-apc]/ensure: ensure changed 'purged' to 'latest'
notice: /Stage[third]/Php/Package[php5-mcrypt]/ensure: ensure changed 'purged' to 'latest'
notice: /Stage[third]/Php/Package[php5-xdebug]/ensure: ensure changed 'purged' to 'latest'
notice: /Stage[third]/Php/Package[php5]/ensure: ensure changed 'purged' to 'latest'
notice: /Stage[third]/Php/Service[apache2]/ensure: ensure changed 'running' to 'stopped'
notice: /Stage[third]/Php/Package[php5-fpm]/ensure: ensure changed 'purged' to 'latest'
notice: /Stage[third]/Php/File[php.ini]/content: content changed '{md5}a199da053cb070fcd15210120e49cd20' to '{md5}9291336844ec35b4b45a84e16975a321'
notice: /Stage[third]/Php/Package[php-pear]/ensure: ensure changed 'purged' to 'latest'
notice: /Stage[third]/Php/Package[php-xml-parser]/ensure: ensure changed 'purged' to 'latest'  
notice: /Stage[third]/Php/Package[php5-curl]/ensure: ensure changed 'purged' to 'latest'
notice: /Stage[third]/Php/File[browscap.ini]/ensure: defined content as '{md5}1393b32a89ea6af06e8e419ac4d4944d'
 notice: /Stage[third]/Php/File[www.conf]/content: content changed '{md5}7f7f6459440a5944275303d06866cec2' to '{md5}68cd4723a3549ce1a81959a0fb104ff3'
notice: /Stage[third]/Php::Pear/Exec[pear-update-channel]/returns: executed successfully
notice: /Stage[third]/Php::Pear/Exec[pear-upgrade]/returns: executed successfully
notice: /Stage[third]/Php/Package[libssh2-1-dev]/ensure: ensure changed 'purged' to 'latest'
notice: /Stage[third]/Php::Pear/Exec[pear-config-set]/returns: executed successfully
notice: /Stage[third]/Php::Pear/Exec[pear-channel-discover-pear-phpunit-de]/returns: executed successfully
notice: /Stage[third]/Php::Pear/Exec[pear-channel-discover-components-ez-no]/returns: executed successfully
notice: /Stage[third]/Php::Pear/Exec[pear-channel-discover-pear-symfony-project-com]/returns: executed successfully
notice: /Stage[third]/Php::Pear/Exec[pear-clear-cache]/returns: executed successfully
notice: /Stage[third]/Php::Pear/Exec[pear-install]/returns: executed successfully
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or you could change 'require' on the service to 'subscribe'

```
service { 'php5-fpm':
    ensure => running,
    enable => true,
    subscribe => File['php.ini','www.conf'],
}
```

This would achieve the same.

Subscribe == require + refresh event.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the way to require multiple resources simultaneously is to supply a list ([source](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/techniques.html#how-can-i-require-multiple-resources-simultaneously)):

```
service { 'php5-fpm':
    ensure => running,
    enable => true,
    require => [ File['php.ini'], File['www.conf'] ],
}
```

Then if you intend to also restart the php-fpm service whenever `php.ini` or `www.conf` changes, you would change the above `require` to a `subscribe`:

```
service { 'php5-fpm':
    ...
    subscribe => [ File['php.ini'], File['www.conf'] ],
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So, I got it figured out. Had to add notify to the file block so it would know to restart the service on file change.

```
file { 'www.conf':
    notify  => Service['php5-fpm'],
    path => '/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf',
    ensure => file,
    owner => root,
    group => root,
    source => 'puppet:///modules/php/www.conf',
    require => Package['php5-fpm'],
}
```